# "There are some data after the end of the payload data" on 7zip while extracting a bin file from Gmod workshop

Tags: 7-zip, binary-files

Before we start, this is a [near-identical issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1153751/what-does-there-are-some-data-after-the-end-of-the-payload-data-mean) from 6 years ago, where the answer offered seem less relevant today due to updates to 7Zip.

While using 7zip to extract a bin file downloaded via [SteamCMD](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD), I received the "There are some data after the end of the payload data" issue.

[image]

I am currently using 7zip 19.00, which, according to the original question, should be fine as this bug was only operational on 16.02 or under. I have since upgraded to 22.01 and am still facing identical issues.

Please let me know if more information is required, I am unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "bin" file is likely an archive blob of some kind. Likely it is some "custom" format that encapsulates information on where the data came from or how it is to be applied to an existing installation.

If 7-zip can open it then all that means is that somewhere near the start of the file 7-zip found something resembling an archive in the data.

That it comes from Steam means it is not unsurprising that potentially at the start and end of the file might be either a program or other information that is embedded in the file that another program (Steam) might use to do something more intelligent with the file. Perhaps it needs to extract the core archive and then run commands to patch the main game files, or maybe it just needs to extract the archive blob, or maybe it needs to run installers or so on.

A `.bin` file is not a "standard" archive file extension. It might contain a standard zip archive but that is by no means an absolute certainty.

If everything you need can be extracted then fine, but you do not have 100% standard archives. You have blobs that might contain an archive along with a bunch of other stuff and the error message is telling you exactly that and nothing more or less.

It is up to you to decide whether or not the message is a problem. 7-zip has no clue what you downloaded.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that this, to some extent, is to be expected. In my particular case, I would consider this a problem since the file I've extracted has no file type, and I am expecting a folder with several Source engine compatible assets. Are there any known alternatives for extracting potential Sourced-based archives? I have attempted to use Peazip and Anyburn due to other internet suggestions but have found no success.

Comment: Unless the archive is in some standard format then there isn't much you can do. it is possible that the main data payload is encrypted and what you've found is simply the decryptor or something else inside the file. Likely you need to install the actual blob and get the final files.

Comment: @HFOrangefish You may need to use the SteamCMD method to install the file somewhere: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/SteamCMD#Downloading_an_App

Comment: Thank you. Sadly, I was unable to get this method to work, and resorted to downloading the gma file then unzipping the gma file via Gmod.